# get element names from unmarshalled object class

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, jaxb

after unmarshalling my xml i got a class like this

```
public static class OrderDetails {

        @XmlElement(name = "InitiatorRole", required = true)
        protected String initiatorRole;
        @XmlElement(name = "OriginatorId", required = true)
        protected String originatorId;
        public String getInitiatorRole() {
            return initiatorRole;
        }
        public void setInitiatorRole(String value) {
            this.initiatorRole = value;
        }
        public String getOriginatorId() {
            return originatorId;
        }
        public void setOriginatorId(String value) {
            this.originatorId = value;
        }
     }
```

now i want to print xmlelement names from this class
InitiatorRole
OriginatorId
how to do this..?

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: how to get xmlelement names into list...